# show div under nested div in jquery

Tags: javascript

how to show last div which has same class value in all of it's parent divs.

example:

```
<div id='parent1' style=display:none;>
    <div class='subclass1'>
        <div class='subclass2'>
            <div class='display_value'>Hai</div>
        </div>  
    <div>
<div>

<div id='parent2' style=display:none;>
    <div class='subclass1'>
        <div class='subclass2'>
            <div class='display_value'>Bye</div>
        </div>  
    <div>
<div>
```

Here, I want to show `div` with `class='display_value'` under `div` with `id='parent2'` in jquery.
How can i achieve this.

Comment: None of those divs have the same class

Comment: @ExplosionPills : Could you elaborate.Correct me if I am wrong but I am kind of seeing `divs` with the same class in the above mentioned code.

Comment: @harsha I mean none of the groups of divs with parents have the same class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that `#parent2` is last parent `div`

```
$('#parent2').find('.display_value').show();
```

If you are not sure about that,

`$('.display_value').last()`

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

Comment: please see my edited question. i need display_value for parent1. I used your first statement.but not getting.may you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.display_value:last'); //will get you last div having class "display_value"
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('#parent1 > .subclass1 > .subclass2 > .display_value').show(); //Show Hia`
`$('#parent2 > .subclass1 > .subclass2 > .display_value').show(); //Show Bye`